# Avoid race conditions in Firebase Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an Android application that provides users reserving restaurants and I am using a real-time database in order to store the necessary information, such as the number of empty tables in the restaurant, and the problematic part it is.

Let's say, we have XYZ restaurant that has just one empty table, and 2 users clicked the reserve button on the android app at the same time and try to reserve the table. If race condition occurs, they will reserve the same table, so the empty table counter will be -1, if both of them get this table.

My question is, how to avoid race conditions in Firebase using **real-time database**. I have searched about it and I saw that I should use Firebase transactions, with Cloud Firestore. But I am using the Realtime Database.

Is there a way to implement mutex or a kind of mechanism that locks the shared data between clients?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding:

> My question is, how to avoid race conditions in Firebase using Realtime database.

Simply by using [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions):

> When working with data that could be corrupted by concurrent modifications, such as incremental counters, you can use a transaction operation.

I see you also added a tag with Cloud Firestore, a database which also has this [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) mechanism.

And regarding:

> Let's say, we have XYZ restaurant that has just one empty table, and 2 users clicked the reserve button on the android app at the same time and try to reserve the table. If race condition occurs, they will reserve the same table, so the empty table counter will be -1, if both of them get this table.

That's not gonna happen. If the first user makes the reservation, the second one won't be able to do it.

Comment: How that's not gonna happen? If two users click the reserve button, they see the empty table counter 1 and try to decrement it. Am I wrong ?

Comment: That's the transactions meant for. If one makes the reservation, the other won't be able to do it.

Comment: However, you only need to decrement a value you can use in Firebase Realtime Database [ServerValue.increment(-value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64154276/if-else-question-check-number-equal-or-greater-in-realtime-database/64155443#64155443). Simple as that. But in this way you don't know when you reach zero. So the transactions remain the viable solution.

Comment: thanks. But If I want to update multiple references on database, so there are two critical sections. Can I start the other transaction inside the transaction or start the second transcation inside the complete call back of the first transaction by checking the comitted parameter ? Because, after reservation, I want to update two sections of my database ?

Comment: If you need to update multiple locations in your database atomically, then you should use Firebase Realtime Database [multi location update feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45284468/firebase-how-to-delete-many-entries-at-once/45285242).